# Using yii2 in yii1

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

```
// include the customized Yii class described below
require(__DIR__ . '/../components/Yii.php');

// configuration for Yii 2 application
$yii2Config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/yii2/web.php');
new yii\web\Application($yii2Config); // Do NOT call run(), yii2 app is only used as service locator

// configuration for Yii 1 application
$yii1Config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/yii1/main.php');
Yii::createWebApplication($yii1Config)->run();
```

I am trying to integrate yii2 with already existing yii1 project.I installed yii2 via composer and followed steps given in  http://www.yiiframework.com/download/ link. Now when i am putting the above code in index.php file it's saying web.php not found. So can any one please tell me where is this file web.php and what all other changes do i have to make to get upgraded to yii2.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html) as well.

Comment: I read this but i am still not getting what is web.php file. I am totally new to yii framework so i am not able to get this config/web.php.

Answer (score -1):

Yii2 has three web.php file.

1. backend/config/web.php
2. frontend/config/web.php
3. common/config/web.php

you please check [this](https://github.com/yiiext/yii2-yii-bridge) plugin for integrate yii2 in yii.